# how to grep a specific process from ps in linux?

Tags: linux, grep, ps

when I `ps -af | grep rv` I get lots of result even with something that has service

but I am looking for searching specific process named rv

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "process named rv"? Processes are identified by `PID` (process id, which is a number), not by "name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append the -w argument to grep

```
ps -af | grep -w rv
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `pgrep`, where also the switch `-w` can be used:

```
pgrep -w "rv"
```

The final result is the process ID of the `rv` process.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -af | grep -w rv
```

or

```
ps -af | grep --word-regexp rv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ps -af | grep -w "rv"
```

Alternatively, you could match the term using regex